# Select value from cell having "today's" date in the same row

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have two columns: `Date` and `Price`. I want to pick the value of the cell in the same row as today's date:

[image]

I want to show "today's" price, so supposing "today" is `12 Feb`, then for the above example today's price should show `18`.

How can I do that in Excel?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you paste a screenshot of what you intend to do?

Comment: @rusk I have added the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your two columns are A an B please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A:B,2,0)
```

Comment: Sorry but that is showing me this error. '#N/A;
I think this can work but something needs to be change, I don't know what.

Comment: @PratikSinghal - You have provided data for year 2014 and the current year is 2015. Are you sure you are not mixing the two up as `Today()` will return today's date?

Comment: @pnuts Changing the last argument 0 to FALSE did the work for me. Thank you.
Final Formula I used is 
`=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A2:B18,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @rusk I  have mistakenly provided previous year data. It is 2015 instead of 2014.